# upload file to server by just giving the name of the file

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ftp

I am trying to upload a file from client pc to server by just giving the name of the file with file location in the temp folder.
is there any solution in php or J Query etc.

Comment: You can use [filezilla](http://filezilla-project.org/download.php?type=client&beta=1) like software to connect your PC to server.

Comment: What is your level of expertise with php and jQuery?  Are you looking for a way for you, yourself to upload, or is it functionality for users of your site?

Comment: Are you willing to say `Server` to `Server`?

Comment: not server to server basically there is a file in temp folder that i want to upload to the server. i m using Windows 7 at client side. And VictorKilo i want to upload it manually but dont want to pick it using form

Comment: So, to be clear, you have a file on a client computer (not yours) that you want to automatically pull onto your server using php?  Thankfully, I dont think that is possible. That would be a huge security flaw if you could pull files from others' computers without them selecting the file... Probably not what you wanted to hear, let me know if I'm off track.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well not J Query but Java, It is possible. use client side signed applet to transfer file by name through ftp. I found this [link](http://www.javabeat.net/2007/10/file-upload-and-download-using-java/) very useful. Some problem of security ftp password and username etc, could occur, As applet run on client side. But hope it will give u some direction to solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of ways to do this, really a quick google search would probably yield enough results to keep you busy for a while.  This can be done with pure php, but I have been using a nifty plugin which incorporates jQuery as well.  Its called the [BlueImp jQuery Uploader](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/).  It is cross-browser tested and has a very nice interface.

The developer has a demo on his page.

There are a variety of options which you can use to customize the look and feel of the uploader.  You can also specify the location which it will save, how you want the files to be named, and if you want thumbnails created as well.

### Edit:

From your comments it appears that you are trying to retrieve a file from the client computer without the user selecting the file.  This is not possible and is a security risk.  The user must select the file.  In addition, everyone has a different computer file system.  Each operating system has a different file structure, so you could never rely on that temp folder being in the same place.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible using java applet + php , javaP applet post request using HttpClient library while on server side php will accept this Post Request for more info:

Working code:
http://www.einfobuzz.com/2011/09/upload-file-using-java-swing-and-php.html
HttpClient library:
http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi